# Reading numbers in python

Tags: python

I have a text file:

```
30.154852145,-85.264584254
15.2685169645,58.59854265854
...
```

I have the following python script:

```
count = 0

while True:
        count += 1
        print 'val:',count
        for line in open('coords.txt'):
                c1, c2 = map(float, line.split(','))
                break
        print 'c1:',c1
        if count == 2: break
```

I want `c1 = 15.2685169645` for `val: 2`. Can someone please tell me what I am messing up on?

Comment: An nice alternative for reading csv-files containing numerical data in python is to use [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). Another one is [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-read-csv-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own loop:

```
with open('coords.txt') as f:
    count = 1
    while True:
        for line in f:
            print 'val: {}'.format(count)
            c1, c2 = map(float, line.split(','))
            print("c1 = {!r}".format(c1))
            if count == 2:
                break
            count += 1
        break
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but it is not working still..I may be missing something still...it just outputs c1 = 30.154852145...I want the if statement to dictate how many values of c1 I want...so if I say if count == 2 then it should output c1 = 30.154852145 in the first loop and then c1 = 15.2685169645 in the next iteration

Comment: I edited but unless you are doing something outside the for loop with the values, the while loop is unnecessary

Comment: I am sorry...it is doing that, but it does not output the previous one....say I have 4 total coords and I set the if statement to break at count == 3 then I would like to have the first three values output at each run of the while loop..if this makes sense?

Comment: I have edited to output all values up to and including count but as I said in my comment you can do this with just the for loop

Comment: awesome...this is what I needed...thanks a lot...however it does not output all the decimal places -- is it possible to get all of them?

Comment: can you give me an example of a number that it does it with?

Comment: it truncates 40.11676013732333 to 40.1167601373

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64032/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-user2468702).

Comment: @user2468702, I edited, you were seeing the formatted output, I added `!r` to the format to print the repr output

Comment: just heading to gym, ask your questions in chat and I will answer when I return

Answer (score 3):

By reopening the file each time, you start reading from the start again.

Just open the file once:

```
with  open('coords.txt') as inputfile:
    for count, line in enumerate(inputfile, 1):
        c1, c2 = map(float, line.split(','))
        print 'c1:',c1
        if count == 2: break
```

This also uses the file object as [a context manager](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)  so the `with` statement will close it for you once done, and uses [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to do the counting.

Comment: thanks...I actually need the while loop in there for other computations...please read my message to @Cyber below. can you please edit it with the code I put up?

Comment: @user2468702: you'd still use the `with` statement to open the file object just once. Put your `while` loop where the `for` loop is now, and call `inputfile.readline()` or `next(inputfile)` to get your next line.